# Save and read image but I can not find it when I open the folder

Tags: android, file, kotlin, save

I have a strange problem. I am developing an android app with Kotlin.

My codes can generate and save the image **myImg.png** to the following directory

**directory: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.MyApp1/files/AutoDDD"**

and also it can read the same image from the same directory and show on imageView

Also, the satement;

```
file.exists()
```

returns true. However, the problem is that I can not see the image file when I open the folder AutoDDD on my laptop. I removed the application and re-installed, but the problem still occurs. I closed the editor and re-opened, re-run the app, but the problem still occurs.

What is the reason?

Comment: If you remove the application that file will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too, the folder and the file exist but i cannot see it. So
put this in Mainfesx.xml

```
...
   <provider
           android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/paths" />
  </provider>
...
```

then create **xml** folder inside (app > src > main > res) , on **xml** folder add **paths.xml** finally in paths.xml add this code

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>//specify your image path here
</paths>
```

on Your activity

```
val imagePath = File(Context.getFilesDir(), "images")//put your path here
val newFile = File(imagePath, "ur_image.png")//put your image here
val contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile)
```

**Warning**: make sure you allow **storage permission** in setting > app > " ur app" > permission > storage & allow it
, in Mainfest add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

seen this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider
it may help you
Thanks!